# find and get data in large amount of SQL table

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, large-data

I have a simple DB table with ONLY 5 columns with no primary key having **7 billion+(7,50,01,771)** data. yes, you read it correctly. it has one cluster index.

**DB table columns**

[image: ZipFrom ZipTo Total_Time Total_Length ChangeDate]

**Cluster index**

[image]

if I write a simple select query to get data, it is taking 7-8 minutes to return data. now, you get my next question. what are the techniques that I can apply to this DB table? So that I can get data in time.

in the actual scenario, where I am using this table have join with 2 temp tables that have WHERE clause and filtered data. Please find below my query for reference.

```
SELECT dt.ZipFrom, dt.ZipTo, dt.Total_time, sz.storelocation, sz.AcctShip, sz.Licensee,sz.Entity from #Zips z INNER join DriveTime_ZIPtoZIP dt on zipFrom = z.zip INNER join #storeZips sz on ZipTo = sz.zip order by z.zip desc, total_time asc
```

Thanks

Comment: *"if I write a simple select query to get data"* Define a "simple" select query. `SELECT SingleColumn FROM YourTable WHERE SomeColumn = 1;`? Considering you have no PK, do you at least have some indexes on the table? Are any of them `CLUSTERED`?

Comment: yes, I have a clustered index in my table. check my updated question.

Comment: Does your query have a WHERE clause? Add the query to your question.

Comment: I would suggest a columnstore index. And probably a nonclustered index. Time to google and look at some Microsoft documentation.

Comment: [edit] your question, @Krunal , don't put that information in the comments.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the relevant query, the temp table definitions *with indexes*, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Description updated...

Comment: Is this table compressed?  If not - I would compress the table and then consider adding additional indexes.

Comment: I have optimized the query to narrow down the execution time from 8+ min to 3.5 min.
Changes made:
(1) put dbo. at an actual table. so that it does not traverse in the whole DB to search for that object type.
(2) set with (nolock) in every table calling in the SP
(3) Create a non-cluster index on one column

Still, I have a couple of questions 
(1) I have a UDF of string split in where clause. does that slow down the query performance? Should I have to also optimize that?
(2) Query execution time is variable. sometimes it takes 3min, 4min, 7min. what to do about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can index according to the **where conditions** in the query. However, this comes at a cost: Storage.

**Order by** statement is also important. If you have to use order by in your query, you can also index accordingly.

But do not forget, the cost of indexing ...

Comment: I have optimized the query to narrow down the execution time from 8+ min to 3.5 min.
Changes made:
(1) put dbo. at actual table. so that it do not traverse in whole DB to search for that object type.
(2) set with (nolock) in every table calling in the SP
(3) Create a non-cluster index on one column

Still, I have a couple of questions 
(1) I have a UDF of string split in where clause. does that slow down the query performance? Should I have to also optimize that?
(2) Query execution time is variable. sometimes it takes 3min, 4min, 7min. what to do about that?

Comment: Yes. Split or functions are also reason of slow in where conditions. i think that is real reason. So What can you do? for example: if your dadas are static, you can create a column and full it with your string split in where clause and use this column in your where conditions, if your dadas are not static do it again and write this column what you need at insert and update time... after that use this column, not use functions in your where. i hope i could explain what i think...

Comment: pls, share to me what you think on this ?